# Android: Background process every 10 seconds: Doesn't work with postdelayed()

Tags: android, process, background

I like to have an Android background process who starts every 10 seconds. This 10 seconds must be more or less exactly (9 to 15 seconds is OK).
I try to implement this using a postdelayed() call (class Handler and Runnable). This works fine if the app is in foreground or the smartphone (a Huawei) is connected to the power. But if it is not connected to the power, it works not. There are waiting times up to 5 minutes between the calls.

Any ideas why?
Another solution to solve that?

Thanks.
Hans

Comment: Share the code that you used.

Comment: I always get strange things on Huawei phones,  so did you test on other devices?

Comment: This could be caused by the doze mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html. And for Huawei devices: They have additionally included their own power management, which is hard to handle programmatically. For an app, there are 3 or 4 settings to include or separate them from different proccesses.

Comment: Hi

I have not tested on another device, actually I have none.

I think the problem is the power management of the Huawei, but I don't sure. I used simple code (a postdelayed example) to test the whole thing and I think the code is correct.

But one question: Could it be the context of the code? I added it to a service.

Thanks a lot
Hans